# json-LD class property relationship modeling

Tags: json, rdf, json-ld, rdfs

I am trying to figure out the best way to model a property / class relationship with JSON-LD. I'm trying to support classes being able to share properties.

The first example uses what I think is the common way to achieve this (although schema.org uses a hosted property called http://schema.org/domainIncludes instead of the rdfs:domain).

However I think my use case would be better described by pointing to properties from the class as in example 2.

Ex 1) See rdfs:domain in properties.

```
{
  "@context": {
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "rdfs": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#",
    "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
    "project": "http://wwww.hello.com#"
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "project:ClassOne",
      "@type": "rdfs:Class",
      "rdfs:label": "ClassOne"
    },
    {
      "@id": "project:ClassTwo",
      "@type": "rdfs:Class",
      "rdfs:label": "ClassOne"
    },
    {
      "@id": "project:propertyOne",
      "@type": "rdf:Property",
      "rdfs:label": "propertyOne",
      "rdfs:range": "xsd:string",
      "rdfs:domain": [
        { "@id":"project:ClassOne" },
        { "@id":"project:ClassTwo" },
      ]
    },
    {
      "@id": "project:PropertyTwo",
      "@type": "rdf:Property",
      "rdfs:label": "PropertyTwo",
      "rdfs:range": "xsd:string",
      "rdfs:domain": [
        { "@id":"project:ClassOne" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Ex 2) Instead of using domains on properties, point to properties from classes. Use ref:isDefinedBy or project:custom/propertyList as two possible ways. I would use one or the other, not both.

```
{
  "@context": {
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "rdfs": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#",
    "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
    "project": "http://wwww.hello.com#"
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "project:ClassOne",
      "@type": "rdfs:Class",
      "rdfs:label": "ClassOne",
      "rdfs:isDefinedBy": [
        { "@id":"project:propertyOne" },
        { "@id":"project:propertyTwo" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@id": "project:ClassTwo",
      "@type": "rdfs:Class",
      "rdfs:label": "ClassOne",
      "project:custom/propertyList": [
          { "@id":"project:propertyTwo" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@id": "project:propertyOne",
      "@type": "rdf:Property",
      "rdfs:label": "propertyOne",
      "rdfs:range": "xsd:string"
    },
    {
      "@id": "project:propertyTwo",
      "@type": "rdf:Property",
      "rdfs:label": "propertyTwo",
      "rdfs:range": "xsd:string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Does this make sense, or am I fundamentally missing something? The reason I don't want to use domain on properties is because I am trying to build a framework where classes from different 'projects' are able to share properties, and it would not make sense for a property in project1 to have a domain of a class in project2.

It does make sense for a class in project1 to use a property in project2 however.

Answer (score 2):

Most people working in RDFS/OWL vocabularies tend to model in Turtle or RDF/XML, but JSON-LD is a fine way to do this.

What is often not appreciated about rdfs:domain (and rdfs:range) is that if two or more classes are used, you're actually creating an intersection, not a union; this is two the inference nature of RDFS. When you have an instance which uses propertyOne, it automatically infers that that instance is a subclass of all of its domains (and that values are subclasses of all ranges). This is why schema:domainIncludes was created, but it has no formal inference rules.

Another way to model is to use owl:unionOf, so that you can say that the domain is a subclass of a class which is the union of two or more other classes, but this is fairly complicated, which again is why schema.org decided to go in a different direction.

In example two, you seem to be suggesting a different way of describing a vocabulary. Note that rdfs:isDefinedBy also has a particular meaning, and I've not seen it use to describe property relationships before. Of course, structurally, you could include the property definitions under both ClassOne and ClassTwo, using @reverse. The key is looking at the triples it creates, which is why Turtle is often better suited for vocabulary modeling, or a purpose-build Protégé. Once that's done, you can serialize as JSON-LD, possibly using some framing to create the structure you're interested in.

Comment: Ok I will think some more about this, I don't believe I am qualified to 'suggest a different way of describing a vocabulary' with my current knowledge, so I'll add an update after some more research.